# Newtonsoft converter with DI

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, json.net, converters

I created custom converter and it work! But now I added service in it and can't register converter in Startup.cs

```
public class CustomGuidConverter : JsonConverter<Guid>
{
    private readonly ILocalizerService localizer;

    public CustomGuidConverter(ILocalizerService localizer)
    {
        this.localizer = localizer;
    }

    /// <inheritdoc/>
    public override Guid ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, [AllowNull] Guid existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var rawValue = reader?.Value?.ToString() ?? string.Empty;
        if (Guid.TryParse(rawValue, out Guid value))
        {
            return value;
        }
  
        throw new JsonReaderException(localizer.Get(LocalStrings.ConvertingError, rawValue));
    }

    /// <inheritdoc/>
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, [AllowNull] Guid value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        writer.WriteValue(value.ToString());
    }
}
```

But when I register it in Startup.cs I should create object witch dependency.

```
.AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
                {
                    options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new CustomGuidConverter(--inject service here--));
                    options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new CustomDecimalConverter());
                    options.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
                });
```

How Can do it?

Answer (score 0):

To configure options with DI, you need to register options configurator

create your class

```
public class NewtonsoftOptionsConfigurator : IPostConfigureOptions<MvcNewtonsoftJsonOptions>
{
    public NewtonsoftOptionsConfigurator(
        //You can inject services here
        )
    {

    }

    public void PostConfigure(string name, MvcNewtonsoftJsonOptions options)
    {
        //Configure options here
    }
}
```

You then need to register your configurator after you add newtonsoft json options into your services collection

```
services.AddSingleton<IPostConfigureOptions<MvcNewtonsoftJsonOptions>, NewtonsoftOptionsConfigurator>();
```

Comment: Please accept answer if it worked for you